# Javascript Password Page

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

I have created a password protect page. The situation is this, when you enter the password protect page, it will ask for your password, when you enter the correct password the content will show if not, it will again still ask for the correct one. In my situation, even if I enter the correct password, it is still looking for the correct password.

Though I have realized my mistake, I still don't know how to correct it. The mistake I did is, I have only one function in my submit button so if the submit button in the access denied form is shown, it is still going back to the original form.

Can someone help on this one. Thank you so much in advance.

[See this link](https://practicecodes-chum.c9.io/password.html)

```
<script>
function password(){
var password = document.getElementById('pw').value;
if (password==123456){
    document.getElementById('1354423021').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('1066133308').style.display = 'none';
}
else
   {
    document.getElementById('1551787368').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('1066133308').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div dm:templateorder="1" class="dmDefaultRespTmpl" id="1811148618">
 <div class="innerPageTmplBox dmDefaultPage  dmRespRowsWrapper dmRespRowsWrapperSize1" id="1536984083" style="min-height: 362px;">
  <div class="dmRespRow dmReadySection" dm:templateid="ContactUs" id="1827814270">
   <div class="dmRespColsWrapper ContactUsSection" id="1299906644">
    <div class="dmRespCol small-12 medium-12 large-12" id="1039282650">
     <!-- *** INSERT YOUR HTML BELOW *** -->
     <div class="dmform default dmContactDefaultForm" preserve_css="true" dmle_widget="dudaContactUsRespId" id="1695446506">
      <h3 class="dmform-title dmwidget-title" id="1231366131" hide="false">
       Sample Password Protect
      </h3>
      <div class="dmform-wrapper" preserve_css="true" id="1072124085">
       <form method="post" class="dmRespDesignRow" locale="ENGLISH" id="1066133308">
        <div class="dmforminput required small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol" id="1525691246">
         <label for="dmform-0" id="1160733053">
          Enter password to view content:
         </label>
         <input type="password" name="dmform-0" style="margin-left: 20px;" id="1410499183"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-0" value="Name" id="1625837675"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width: 150px;" class="dmformsubmit dmWidget R" preserve_css="true" id="1382804230">
         <input class="" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="1532566041" onclick="password()"/>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
      <input name="dmformsendto" type="hidden" value="" preserve_css="true" id="1955950480"/>
      <input class="dmActionInput" type="hidden" name="action" value="/_dm/s/rt/widgets/dmform.submit.jsp" id="1702158220"/>
      <input name="dmformsubject" type="hidden" value="Form Message" preserve_css="true" id="1329461076"/>
     </div>
     <div class="dmform default dmContactDefaultForm" preserve_css="true" dmle_widget="dudaContactUsRespId" id="1439487325">
      <h3 class="dmform-title dmwidget-title" id="1325046572" hide="true">
      </h3>
      <div class="dmform-wrapper" preserve_css="true" id="1139343276">
       <form method="post" style="display:none;" class="dmRespDesignRow" locale="ENGLISH" id="1551787368">
        <div class="dmforminput required small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol" id="1306176401">
         <label for="dmform-0" id="1114107505">
          Access Denied
         </label>
         <input type="password" name="dmform-0" style="margin-left: 20px;" id="pw"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-0" value="Enter password to view content" id="1369838574"/>
         <label style="color:red;">
          Incorrect Password!
          <br/>
          Please try Again.
         </label>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width: 150px;" class="dmformsubmit dmWidget R" preserve_css="true" id="1170923147">
         <input class="" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="1040411433" onclick="password()"/>
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
      <input name="dmformsendto" type="hidden" value="" preserve_css="true" id="1116836665"/>
      <input class="dmActionInput" type="hidden" name="action" value="/_dm/s/rt/widgets/dmform.submit.jsp" id="1195111197"/>
      <input name="dmformsubject" type="hidden" value="Form Message" preserve_css="true" id="1609194082"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dmRespRow dmDefaultListContentRow" style="text-align:center; display:none;" id="1354423021">
   <div class="dmRespColsWrapper" id="1466630272" style="">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 dmRespCol" id="1920496987" style="">
     <!-- *** INSERT YOUR HTML BELOW *** -->
     <div class="dmCustomHtml" id="1788238217" dmle_class="true" dmle_widget="html">
      <div style="text-align: left;">
       SHOW CONTENT
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no point to implementing a password in client-side javascript, it won't stop anyone who wants in.

Comment: i know. but I'm only doing this for a school homework. we were just asked to do this simple coding @dandavis

Comment: check the IDs in your function, you have 3 different ones where i would expect to see 2 or 4 different ones...

Comment: thank you so much @dandavis, you were right! it took me hours to look for the right id.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple javascript format..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Password:</br>
<input type="password" id="password">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="login"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if(password == '12345'){
      document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = "Success!";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = "Wrong password!";
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```